# Wordpress ACF - как вывести тип поля Повторитель внутри повторителя.. и вложенные поля?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Всем привет
Я создал тип поля ПОВТОРИТЕЛЬ внутри которого есть еще один повторитель со своими полями...

Такая конструкция:

-ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ(повторитель)

-----Иконка
   -----Вопрос
   -----Ответ

-----КНОПКА(повторитель)
   --------Текст кнопки
   --------Ссылка кнопки

Как это вывести?

**ответ**

```
 $repeater = get_field( 'faqhome' );
                foreach( $repeater as $item ) {
                  foreach ( $item['voprosq'] as $subitem ) {
                    echo $subitem['otvett'];
                  }
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете репитер через `get_field`. Затем с помощью `foreach` перебираете елементы:

```
$repeater = get_field( 'repeater_field_name' );
foreach( $repeater as $item ) {
    var_dump( $item );
    foreach ( $item['repeater_inside_repeater_field_name'] as $subitem ) {
        var_dump( $subitem );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) очень помогли

Answer (score -1):

вы что за дич пишите, во реальный код с реального сайта

```
<? foreach ($data['articles'] as $articles) { ?>                  
<div class="h3__h4">
    <div class="h3__article lato4-48-58 color-fff"><?= $articles["rules_header"] ?></div>

    <div class="h4__article ptsans4-24-31 color-fff"> <?= $articles["rules_text"] ?></div>

    <div class="h5data__h4opentex">
        <div class="h5data ptsans4-24-31 color-333">13.07.2022</div>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="h4opentex ptsans4-24-31 color-333">Подробнее 
                <img class="h4opentex-img" 
                    src="/wp-content/themes/your-clean-template-3/img/right_sl.svg" alt=""> 
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<? } ?>
```